# Remove items multi select with optgroup in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-multiselect

Is there a way to clear all option and optgroup HTML elements by using jquery?

My HTML select element is like this,

```
<select id="users" name="multiselect" multiple="multiple" style="width:382px;" >
    <optgroup id="groupadmin" label="Group Admin"></optgroup>
    <optgroup id="systemusers" label="System User"></optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes there is; have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried following ways,

$('#users').empty(); 
$('#users').find('optgroup,option').remove();
$('#users').html($('#users').html().replace('selected',''));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**.empty()**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

> Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

*Code*

```
$('#users').empty()
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAFnY/)

### EDIT

As you are using [multiSelect](https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect) plugin, You need to use `.multiSelect('refresh')` method.

```
$('#users').empty().multiSelect('refresh');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4P8Cs/)

Comment: I have used it. but didn't clear the optgroups and options..!!

Comment: yeah i have seen that.. but it doesn't work for me. I have used styling for above select element in jquery as this : "$('#users').multiselect();" 
will it be effect to unclear select?

Comment: its doesn't supported by used library.
"../../js/jquery.uix.multiselect.js"
Is it any other way satpal?

Comment: @Kanishka, As per [Docs](https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect/wiki/API-Documentation) it has refres method

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   $('#users').find('optgroup,option').remove();
```

Comment: I have tried it by mentioned way, but it does not help to remove optgroup option elements..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
$('#users').children().remove();
```

This will work irrespective of whether an optgroup is present or not

Comment: unfortunately its not remove any of items in select element..
Does it happens because of used library?

Comment: $('#users).empty(); doesn't work for me. I have tried many ways, but nothing happen to the select element. its used library for styling ../../js/jquery.uix.multiselect.js

Comment: I think the library for styling doesn't affect how the code works. Not sure though